# Adding a TTTableViewController (from three20) to another UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, three20

I'm having a problem with `three20` that I'm hopeful someone will be able to help me out with.

I have a `TTTableViewController` that I use very similarly to how the `TTTwitter` app in `three20`'s sample projects uses it. I have just three methods that I'm implementing: `(id)init`, `(void)createModel`, and `(id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate`. And I've subclassed `TTListDataSource` and `TTURLRequestModel` for my data. To summarize, it's a fairly simple use of `TTTableViewController`, I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary.

When I add this `TTTableViewController` to a descendant of `UIView`, it works just fine. It loads and displays the data perfectly. For example, the following two work fine:

```
FooTableViewController *controller = [[FooTableViewController alloc] init];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(288, 20, 480, 1004);
[self.window addSubview:controller.view];
```

As does this:

```
FooTableViewController *controller = [[FooTableViewController alloc] init];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(288, 20, 480, 1004);

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
// a bunch of scrollView variable initializations..
[scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
[self.window addSubview:scrollView];
```

The problem arises when I try to add `FooTableViewController` (which, again, is a subclass of `TTTableViewController`) to the `view` of a descendant of `UIViewController`. The following, for example, doesn't work:

```
FooTableViewController *controller = [[FooTableViewController alloc] init];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(288, 20, 480, 1004);

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 768, 1004);
[viewController.view addSubview:controller.view];

[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Any idea why this happens? Like I said, it works just fine when I add it to a `UIView` (that is, one that's not in a `UIViewController`), but doesn't when I try to add it to a `UIViewController`. Besides trying to add it like I did above, I also tried subclassing `UIViewController` and adding it from within. No luck.

Thanks!

**EDIT** I should be a little more clear on what I mean by "it doesn't work." All I see is an empty table -- just empty rows. Putting a breakpoint on `createModel` indeed shows that that method is not being called. Thanks!

**UPDATE** diwup totally pointed me towards the right solution. He was right in that it is because `TTTableViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` weren't getting called. I verified this by subclassing `UIViewController` (I called it `FooViewController`) and adding the `TTTableViewController` to its `view` from within the class (I called the `TTTableViewController` variable `controller`). I also overrode two methods like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [controller viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [controller viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

And, lo and behold, it worked! Of course, this isn't a long-term solution, I still want to figure out how to get `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` called by itself.

**UPDATE2** I decided to just override `viewDidLoad:` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
    [super viewDidAppear:NO];
}
```

I'm not too pleased with it, it seems hacky (and I should probably make sure `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` don't get called twice), but I'm ready to call it a day with it.

Comment: The solution works! If there is a better solution it will be great.. To keep each controller and calling viewWillAppear is too troublesome if using many tt controlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer may not be relevant. But I suspect that the problem may have something to do with the **addSubview:** method. Since **addSubview:** doesn't guarantee the view is on the top level of the view hierarchy, certain methods of that view may not get fired during or after **addSubview:**. These methods include **viewWillAppear:**, **viewDidAppear:** etc etc.

Therefore, if Three20's code relies on those interface methods, things could go wrong. I would suggest you try to present that controller modally and see what will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's definitely given me something to explore. I believe I'm about to learn more about `UIViewController`s very soon... :)

Comment: Actually.. Just realized that my sample for making it work does basically the same thing... It adds the `view` to another `UIView` without loading the `TTTableViewController` modally. Hmmm.. But regardless, thanks for getting me thinking in this direction. :)

Comment: I settled for a solution that doesn't seem all that clean to me, as you can see in my updates. Again, thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

The same question.

Just call the instace of TTTableViewController ;

for example:

```
  TTTableViewController tableViewController;
  [tableViewController createModel]
```

and

```
  [tableViewController updateView]
```

in viewDidLoad.

it's works.